# Does a generator decorator exist?

Tags: python, twisted

I just got through tracking down a random bug while using Twisted:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/spread/pb.py", line 826, in proto_message
    self._recvMessage(self.localObjectForID, requestID, objectID, message, answerRequired, netArgs, netKw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/spread/pb.py", line 840, in _recvMessage
    netResult = object.remoteMessageReceived(self, message, netArgs, netKw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/spread/flavors.py", line 114, in remoteMessageReceived
    state = method(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1141, in unwindGenerator
    return _inlineCallbacks(None, f(*args, **kwargs), Deferred())
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1020, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
exceptions.AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

This was caused by:

```
@defer.inlineCallbacks
def myfunc():
    # Function implementation with no yield statement.
```

And when the `myfunc` was called, I would get the previous traceback printed but with everything within the function working properly. This is because it returned `None` instead a generator when called, which `defer.inlineCallbacks` expects to be returned. Is there way to declare a function a generator without placing a yield statement within the function body? Such as a generator decorator?

Comment: " Is there way to declare a function a generator without placing a yield statement within the function body?"  No.  How would this solve your problem?

Comment: If your function is not a generator (no `yield` in it) then it makes no sense to use `@defer.inlineCallbacks`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Jochen Ritzel: I was expecting that I would use a yield statement within the function so I decorated it with `inlineCallbacks` because a bunch of similar functions did contain yields, but by chanse I never ended up using a yield in that particular function.

Comment: S.Lott: If I could do say, `@inlineCallbacks\n@generator\ndef myfunc:pass`, then `myfunc` would be guaranteed to return a generator to prevent the problem because twisted does not raise an exception when `inlineCallbacks` decorates a non-generator function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others have noted, this likely makes no sense. But for completeness and to answer the question:

**No**, you have to use a `yield` to make it a generator, except of course if you create a decorator that's a generator (by including the `yield` keyword) itself but doesn't actually yield anything and just calls the decorated function. Such a `yield` can be unreachable and pointless (`if False: yield`), but it has to be there. As this isn't a common need, there is nothing like the latter pre-built, at least nothing I'm aware of. The by far simplest way is to just add this to your function, writing your own decorator isn't worth it for a few cases and should you need it frequently, there's probably something wrong without your design and you should fix that instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need it, make one up.

```
#like this
def generator(callable):
    def asgenerator(*args, **kwargs):
        while True:
            yield callable(*args, **kwargs)
    return asgenerator
```

Although, as noted by others, this is probably hiding a design problem.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've bumped into [Ticket 2501](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/2501).  This is already fixed in trunk, and the error you encounter will be much clearer in the future.

Comment: +1: This is the cause of my problem (except for not realizing I was not using a yield statement) but @delnan directory answered my question.